# Trumbowyg: Can't get the textarea value in PHP

Tags: laravel, wysiwyg, trumbowyg

I'm trying to use a WYSIWYG editor in my Laravel application but I have a bug I can't solve.

What works:

- A form that sends a post request with a text area filled (name = pitch)
- So the request is well formed and I can retrieve it in my controller, everything is perfect

**My Problem**

When I add a WYSIWYG editor on this specific textarea (with Trumbowyg or Redactor, I tried both), then `pitch` disappears from the request and I can't get it on the controller.

I don't have any JS issue in the console, when I delete the call to the WYSIWYG editor, everything is fine, so I don't know where to search.

DB field for `pitch` is `text` (I tried switching it to `string`, but didn't work either).

Here is my view code:

```php
         <tr>
             <td>{!! Form::label('pitch', 'Pitch') !!}</td>
             <td>{!! Form::textarea('pitch','',array('class' => 'pitch')) !!}</td>
         </tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#pitch').trumbowyg({
            resetCss: true
        });             
    });
</script>
```

And in the Controller, this code gives me `null`

```php
dd($request->input('pitch'));
```

[Mode Code Sample in this gist](https://gist.github.com/YannDecoopman/981169d01341e99569a6)

Comment: Have you tried `dd($request->all())` to see what is in the request? Perhaps the name got changed by the js?

Comment: Thank you @haakym i tried and get all the other form fields right but not the one i want (pitch)

    `array:9 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "1mMt0YL0qKcpEHYtxJoHbb6mNjG5zFh7nsaTMUB9"
  "name" => "TestAAA"
  "url" => "http://testaaa.fr"
  "country" => "FR"
  "priority" => "3"
  "statut" => "Blacklisté"
  "template" => "0"
  "taganalytics" => ""
]`

Comment: make sure the textarea name is pitch when you inspect. the wysiwyg JS might be removing the name from the element. MaterialNote is also a pretty good wysiwyg wit its own flaws

Comment: @KetA you're welcome, that's weird! Can you check `view source` and double check the blade directives are outputting the `textarea` code as expected. If using chrome perhaps you could try watching the network tab to see what is submitted by the form.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how your wysiwig code is even working actually. Your blade is `Form::textarea('pitch','',array('class' => 'pitch'))` There's no `id` in sight, yet your js to set the wysiwig is looking for the id `$('#pitch').trumbowyg({`?

Comment: @Chris 
The text area name and id and class are all "pitch"

Laravel is automatically setting an id up to "pitch" so the js is finding the textarea but you're right, i corrected it (but that doesn't solve my problem)
I'll look through Chrome network tab

Comment: So with Google Network the post request is:

_method:PUT
_token:dqpzy4zKZLJFwr5uVK9F5KotYIZQy4uuo4KbyT6P
name:TestAAA
url:http://testaaa.fr
country:FR
priority:3
statut:Blacklisté
template:0
taganalytics:

So, still doesn't contains "pitch"

Comment: @KetA do a console serialize for the textarea and check its value. What you put in the wysiwyg might not be reflecting in the textarea as the wysiwyg creates a separate node to show wysiwyg insides. if you put something in and do a serialize in JS console `$("textarea[name='pitch']").serialize()` and nothing returns. You will probably have to prevent submit, populate REAL textarea with the wysiwyg contents and then continue with the submit. Had to do this with materialNote

Comment: Actually, When i try `$("textarea[name='pitch']").serialize()` in js console i do get what i type in the wisywyg...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a friend of mine helped me to catch the problem.
Thank you very much @Chris & @ haakym

So the problem is an HTML conflict, my form was imbricated in a table and that made a parsing conflit so  i put the begining and the closing of the form outside of the table and now it's fine.

I would certainly never have found that by myself because everything else was working fine, but you know that's what they call experience !

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end. Thanks for sharing the answer. I wouldn't have thought about checking the tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I had the same issue.